# Unable to create partition for Android installation in VMWare

Tags: partitioning, android, vmware

I'm trying to create an Android (android-x86-5.1-rc1.iso) Virtual Machine in VMWare Player 7.1.4. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and tried to follow this instructions ([Using VMWare to replace the slow Android Emulator](http://visualgdb.com/tutorials/android/vmware/)).

When reaching the “Create/Modify partitions” (step 11) I get an error saying "OK. There is no hard drive to edit partitions.":

[image: "OK. There is no hard drive to edit partitions"]

I've been looking for [solutions](https://superuser.com/questions/915955/android-installer-cant-find-hard-drive-in-vmware-esxi) but the answers are not clear to me as I'm not very familiar with linux OS, or the jargon.

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It was saying there is no hard drive to edit partitions. 
I just restarted my PC and everything worked OK after that.